# How can I set a call intent on different list view items?

Tags: android, listview

I'm pretty new to developing, I am working on a school project and I would like to set call action intents to different items on a listView.
I got the onClickListener set on each item I would like to pass the intent but I can't figure how to get them to call each specific phone number.

Here's my code
 ` public class WordAdapter extends ArrayAdapter implements View.OnClickListener {

```
    /**
     * Create a new {@link WordAdapter} object.
     *
     * @param context is the current context (i.e. Activity) that the adapter is being created in.
     * @param words is the list of {@link Word}s to be displayed.
     */

    public WordAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Word> words) {
        super(context, 0, words);

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
        View listItemView = convertView;
        if (listItemView == null) {
            listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                    R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        }

        // Get the {@link Word} object located at this position in the list
        Word currentWord = getItem(position);

        // Find the TextView in the list_item.xml layout with the ID 
        TextView titleTextView = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.title_name);
        titleTextView.setText(currentWord.getTitleId());

        // Find the TextView in the list_item.xml layout with the ID 
        TextView priceTextView = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.price_name);
        // Get the default translation from the currentWord object and set this text on
        // the default TextView.
        priceTextView.setText(currentWord.getPriceId());

        // Find the TextView in the list_item.xml layout with the ID 
        TextView hoursTextView = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.hours_name);
        hoursTextView.setText(currentWord.getHoursClearwaterId());

        // Find the TextView in the list_item.xml layout with the ID 
        TextView phoneTextView = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.phone_name);
        phoneTextView.setText(currentWord.getPhoneClearwaterId());
        //Set the OnlcickListener for this view
        phoneTextView.setOnClickListener(this);

        // Find the TextView in the list_item.xml layout with the ID 
        TextView webTextView = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.web_name);
        webTextView.setText(currentWord.getWebClearwaterId());
        phoneTextView.setOnClickListener(this);

        // Find the ImageView in the list_item.xml layout with the ID image.
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_icon);
        // Check if an image is provided for this word or not
        if (currentWord.hasImage()) {
            // If an image is available, display the provided image based on the resource ID
            imageView.setImageResource(currentWord.getImageResourceId());
            // Make sure the view is visible
            imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            // Otherwise hide the ImageView (set visibility to GONE)
            imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        // Return the whole list item layout (containing 2 TextViews) so that it can be shown in
        // the ListView.
        return listItemView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.phone_name:
                Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                callIntent.setData(Uri.parse(**Here the method will get the many different phone numbers from my list data**);
                startActivity(callIntent);
        }

    }
}
```

`

The idea is that the user can click and call different businesses.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so after turning the project my reviewer showed me how to use auto link and I add that to the textviews on the layout then.

so on the list_item those were the changes:

2. android:autoLink=”phone”

   ```
    <TextView
   android:id="@+id/txtViewPhone"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="Phone no: 12345"
   android:autoLink="phone"
   android:textSize="16sp"
   android:layout_margin="5dip">
   </TextView>
   ```
3. android:autoLink=”web"

   ```
   <TextView
   android:id="@+id/txtViewWeb"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="Web: www.pareshnmayani.wordpress.com"
   android:autoLink="web"
   android:textSize="16sp"
   android:layout_margin="5dip">
   </TextView>
   ```

this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

permission in manifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

then on click

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" + "Your phone"));
startActivity(intent);
```

in your case

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" + String.valueOf(word.get(i))));
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may be better off setting the `onClick` listener with an anonymous class so it can capture the current `Word` and use that to generate the right intent

```
final Word currentWord = getItem(position);

phoneTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
        callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+**get from `currentWord`**);
        startActivity(callIntent);
    }
});
```

Comment: When I try this, the code "tel:"+**get from `currentWord`** gives me a error cannot resolve get from. Is there something I am supposed to change in there? thanks

Comment: Yes, you can't just copy and paste this, you have to replace `**get from currentWord**` with however you get the phone number or info from the `Word` class. Maybe `currentWord.getPhoneClearwaterId()`? I don't know what this `Word` class is so you'll have to figure that part out yourself.

Comment: I thought that was the case, sorry, thanks for helping, im trying to implement right now.

Comment: I couldn't get it to work :(. I get all the way to running the app but then it closes on Click. I will do some research and get back to it. thanks anyways

Comment: You could always just hard-code a test phone number to check that the rest of it works. For example `Uri.parse("tel:+18773555787")` (which will call Google customer support). You also need appropriate permissions (`CALL_PHONE`) to be able to make a call.